# Numerical then alphabetical sort of a bi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm really trying hard but failing to sort my bi-dimensional array the way I want in PHP.

I've got an array that stores names and age of persons and looks like:

```
$array[0][0]="Alex"
$array[0][1]=38
$array[1][0]="Peggy"
$array[1][1]=37
$array[2][0]="Ben"
$array[2][1]=38
```

and so on....

I managed to sort this array by age doing the following:

```
usort($DATA, function($a, $b) {
    return $b[1] - $a[1];
});
```

but I would like to add another layer of sorting by doing and alphabetical  sort of person having the same age. So first, the array is sorted by ages then if some ages are identical, an alphabetical sorting is done to have alex first and Ben right after it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`usort()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), "the comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second." So instead of just returning immediately, check if the difference is zero and act accordingly:

```
<?php
$array = [["Alex",38], ["Peggy",37], ["Ben",38]];
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $diff = $b[1] - $a[1];
    if ($diff === 0) {
        $diff = strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    }
    return $diff;
});
print_r($array);
```

Here we use the [`strcmp()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php), which "returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal" just as we need.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Alex
            [1] => 38
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ben
            [1] => 38
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Peggy
            [1] => 37
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks. it works.
I had a big issue because my 'age' was a float var and my sort results weren't right. I've converted them in integer and now it's fine. but I had to go step by step to undersant why your example was actually working and why  once inserted in my code, it wasn't...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and sort by columns (extracting them with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)):

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 1), array_column($array, 0), $array);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc269cb890ba106110d7743eb7f9a7c438e2506e).

Comment: Interesting approach, never worked with `array_column` before.